# Session storage keys such as getItem, setItem and clear are retrieved when looping through all sessionStorage keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, session-storage, sessionstorage

In my web app, I store a few key value pairs in the browser sessionStorage using javascript. The issue I am experienceing is when looping through all keys in SessionStorage, I am getting (presumeably) system keys such as `key`, `getItem`, `setItem`, `removeItem`, `clear`. Using chrome dev tools, I can confirm that these keys do NOT exist in the Key Value table under Session Storage.

For Example:
In sessionStorage, there are 5 keys, for demo purposes named `key_1` to `key_5`.

Using the following code:

```js
sessionStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.setItem("key_1","test_1");
sessionStorage.setItem("key_2","test_2");
sessionStorage.setItem("key_3","test_3");
sessionStorage.setItem("key_4","test_4");
sessionStorage.setItem("key_5","test_5");
var seshString = "";
for (var key in sessionStorage){
 console.log(key);
 if(key != "key_2" && key != "key_3") {
  seshString += "&" + key + "=" + sessionStorage[key];
 }
}
console.log("Loop Complete");
console.log(seshString);
```

I get the following:

    `key_1
    key_2
    key_3
    key_4
    key_5
    length
    key
    getItem
    setItem
    removeItem
    clear
    Loop Complete
    &key_1=test_1&key_4=test_4&key_5=test_5&length=5&key=function key() { [native code] }&getItem=function getItem() { [native code] }&setItem=function setItem() { [native code] }&removeItem=function removeItem() { [native code] }&clear=function clear() { [native code] }`

Where are the extra sessionStorage keys coming from?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to see that in the console?  Are you doing something like `Object.keys(sessionStorage)` ?  Because sessionStorage is an object.  Any property on the object is a key reference to either a value or a method.

Comment: Sorry about that, it looks like the code block I had was deleted. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Yeah, so that's why you are getting that.  Every method on an object is a key reference to the actual method.  `getItem` is a key on the sessionStorage object, which just happens to reference a method.

Comment: So I guess the next question is why are you doing that loop?  I think it's a pretty safe thing to say that usually applications know what variables they expect to exist in something like sessionStorage or localStorage.  There isn't typically a need to loop through the storage to find stuff.  Even if unknowns will exist, I would think it would be much easier to store your data in a single key JSON.stringified, which you can pull and then do your logic on whatever dynamic fields may exist in that JSON.parsed object.

Comment: Ahhh yes that does explain it, thank you!

Comment: It is code that a former colleague wrote. I can only assume it was looped as there are 9 out of 17 keys that are excluded from that seashString variable when compiling the string. So I guess it was done for neatness and to prevent a whole bunch of if(!! key ... ) {..} ? Ah well, I'll be rewriting the code regardless